# Azure Todo List on Local

Tags: debugging, azure, local

Sorry if this is an easy question or solution can be found easly but I can not find it. Unfortunatelly on web finding what you need about Azure is nearly impossible for me as because maybe I don't know how to search because I am a very beginner level web programmer and just started mobile and Azure.

I started native Android development with .Net backend and begin with the tutorial on Azure web page. Now I have the service and mobile app up and running with out any problem. But I can't run and debug it locally. I downloaded the service and when I run it a web page is opened with "http://localhost:59220" address. My machine and phone that I am using for testing is on the same network. I configured my firewall and can telnet it. But phone can not connect to it. Also I can not connect to web page from phone or another computer on the same network. When I try with "192.168.1.100:59220" adress "I got Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400" error both from phone other computer and also from the computer that runs the service. But when I change ip to localhost it works.

How can I connect my phone and debug my todolist service while running on local?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I downloaded the service" and how exactly are you running it?

Comment: I downloaded it from azure web site as it says in the tutorial (tutorial shows ou how to download the tutorial app todo list) from azure management and I published it on the cloud with using vs2015. This publishing worked perfectly. I can connect the service using the app on my phone. But when I run the service on local by pressing F5 it runs and opens the service web site but I can not connect it with my phone. And of course I changed the host address on the phone application. And the other things I wrote on my main message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone cannot access your local server as "localhost". This [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) is mapped to IP address 127.0.0.1 and on your phone that address points to the phone itself and not to the computer you're running the website on.

When you try with 192.168.1.100, your request does reach the local server and is most likely received by [IIS Express](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) - the web server built into Visual Studio which runs your project by default.

IIS Express, however, responds to your request with a `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400`. That is because "192.168.1.100" is not a hostname it is familiar with.

To get a proper response you will need to configure IIS Express to accept requests from 192.168.1.100 or some other hostname. Below are instructions on how to do so, adapted from this blog post: [IIS Express – HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid](http://blog.binarybits.net/applications/iis-express-http-error-400-the-request-hostname-is-invalid/).

1. Exit the IIS Express instant currently running.
2. Open IIS Express’s applicationhost.config located at the following path `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`
3. Find the entry for a particular site (e.g “Azure Todo List” running in port 59220) which you are developing.

e.g.:

```
   <site name="AzureTodoList" id="10">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Projects\BB Apps\AzureTodoList" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59220:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

4. Replace `bindingInformation="*:59220:localhost"` with `bindingInformation="*:59220:*"`

   **Note**: This will make your website ignore the hostname when it responds to requests. This is not the most secure thing to do.
5. Save the file.
6. Start a command prompt in administrator mode and run the following command.

   `netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:6306/ user=Everyone`
7. Now debug the site again and you should be able to access the url using IP address or host name.

Comment: Thank you urig. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Now it says 503 service unavailable but still with local host I can connet to webpage with browser

Answer (score 2):

The answer of urig is the solution that I was looking for but a little addition is needed. If you are using VS2015 applicationhost.config is located on "solution folder of your project".vs\config folder.